# What does it mean - Unless otherwise stated in this document, and except as otherwise provided for herein

Tags: phrase-meaning, legalese

I think I can understand them if I break them apart but I am confused when they are put together in a sentence.

**Unless otherwise stated in this document** - *All conditions remain true unless it is stated differently in this document.*

**and** - in conjunction with

**Except as otherwise provided for herein** -- I think it carries the same meaning as *unless otherwise stated in this document*?

**herein** - *in this document*

Does the sentence repeat itself or it means something else?

Answer (score 1):

The two phrases are actually slightly different: the first (*Except as stated in this document...*) is interpreted as you suggest.

The second is not *quite* the same. A situation may be *provided for herein* by a ‘statement of incorporation’, e.g., there might be a statement that “all provisions described in the Agreement between A and B, signed on such-and-such date are hereby incorporated into this document”. The document does not state in this document that a particular condition has changed, but the Agreement between A and B *does* so state, and by the statement of incorporation, therefore applies to the current document as if stated in it.

***Both phrases are what are commonly called ‘legalese’. You should always ask a lawyer about interpretation, whether or not you feel certain you understand - English as used by the legal profession is NOT the same as ordinary everyday English.***

Comment: I am not a lawyer, nor do I play one on TV. Except for the advice to consult a lawyer, do not take any part of this answer as legal advice.